# Angular 6 Confirmation Dialog directive for mat-button

Tags: angular, button, dialog, angular-directive, confirm

I'd like to use some Angular built-in mechanism to throw the standard confirmation dialog (shown below) on clicking action button inside of material design, without creating additional component.

[image]

And right after "OK" is clicked to return the control flow to function that handled action button click (just discard itself). In case of cancel just close the confirmation modal and do nothing.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work (

```
<mat-cell class="action" *matCellDef="let row">
                                    <button *ngIf="!row.completedOrDiscard" class="discard-build-order" mat-button (click) = "discardBuildOrder(row.buildOrderId)" confirm="Are you sure you want to Discard the build order?">Discard</button>
</mat-cell>
```

Also I tried like this, nothing happens

```
<mat-cell class="action" *matCellDef="let row">
                                    <button *ngIf="!row.completedOrDiscard" class="discard-build-order" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure you want to Discard the build order?" ng-click = "discardBuildOrder(row.buildOrderId)" >Discard</button>
</mat-cell>
```

Comment: Have you tried working with sweet alert ? that should be easier..

Comment: Unfortunately know... Do you have a brief example of how to implement it?